# Translation from Latin to English of "NON ANGLORUM"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I would like to know what is the correct translation of this from Latin to English:

> **NON ANGLORUM**

Is it: not English or none of the English or not of the English? I am stuck.

Comment: Why, please? Why not say when or why you got stuck?

Answer (score 5):

The -orum ending denotes a plural genitive ending, hence:

> *Not of the* [many] *English*

Note that, as Sebastian suggests in the comments, this is not a complete sentence. So for a safer translation we would need to know the context. It might be part of a longer sentence, or the rest might be omitted and to be induced from the preceding text. In absence of a verb, **esse** (to be) is something one would think of, since in Latin it can be omitted, but in this case it doesn't add any especially meaningful information either.

Comment: This probably comes closest, but in itself it's a meaningless expression, and in context it could mean all kinds of thing. E.g. *non Anglorum pristiniae virtutis immemor* or whatever.